# jquery if function in html

Tags: jquery, if-statement

if I use jquery function with cholist as id element in html, am using firefox

```
<a onclick="cholist(this.id)" id="0">Title</a>

<script>
function cholist(id) {
  alert(id);
}
</script>
```

but

```
<script>
function cholist(id) {
  if (id='0'){alert(id);}
  else {alert("no");}
}
</script>
```

does not work

Comment: You wrote `if (id = '0')` using a single equals which means "set", you need to use double equals (`==`) to "compare".

Comment: Thank you, everything I looked up on the web had single quotes.

Comment: The quotes don’t matter.

Comment: `if (id='0')` -> `if (id=='0')` or `if (id==='0')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function cholist(id) {
  alert( id === ‘0’ ? id : ‘no’)
}
```